Horror movie that has a demon hand coming through a mirror
I think this movie was from either the 80's, the late 70's or even the late 80's.
The only parts of this movie that I can recall (I was really young when I watched this with my dad) was a priest (I believe) in a church (I think). I believe there were others with him at one point.
The parts that I do remember seeing are flies on a window, filling it completely. The priest starts to get scared. Then I remember seeing a mirror with a demon hand coming through it, almost like a portal.
My dad said it was Son of Satan, but I cannot find any reference to this, or I think he may have been wrong on the title. It's been bugging me for years and I would love to find out what this movie was. I don't believe it was Prince of Darkness, but again, I'm not 100% certain.

This is bound to be John Carpenter's Prince of Darkness (1987), a religious horror film with a sci-fi twist.

A group of graduate students and scientists uncover an ancient canister in an abandoned church, but when they open the container, they inadvertently unleash a strange liquid and an evil force on all humanity.

The film is mostly set within a church in Los Angeles. The main cast are a priest, a physics professor, and some other scientists and students.


Prince of Darkness (1987)

The plot involves an Anti-God trapped in an antimatter universe who is trying to enter the matter universe with the help of his son, Satan. The antimatter universe is described as the "mirror image" of the matter universe and mirrors can be used as portals between them.
Near the end of the film, Satan -- using the body of a human woman as a vessel -- attempts pull his father into the matter universe through a large mirror. There's a shot of the Anti-God's demonic-looking red hand being pulled through the mirror. The priest (played by Donald Pleasence) witnesses this with a frightened look on his face, while hiding behind a furnace in the same room.



Prince of Darkness (1987)

I didn't find a shot of a window filled with flies in the film, but there is a shot of a window covered in worms, as well as a shot of a window sill crawling with worker ants. You said you watched this when you were "really young," so it'd make sense if your memory of one of these scenes is a little off.



Prince of Darkness (1987)


Flies on a window generally conjures up The Amityville Horror

In the early morning hours on November 13, 1974, Ronald DeFeo Jr. murders his entire family with a rifle at their home of 112 Ocean Avenue in Amityville, New York.
One year later, middle-class newlyweds George and Kathy Lutz move into the house with Kathy's three children from a prior marriage: Greg, Matt, and Amy. Despite George's irreligiosity, Kathy, a nominal Roman Catholic, requests Jesuit priest Father Delaney to bless the home. Delaney arrives while the family is out boating on the Long Island Sound. Upon entering the house, Delaney is swarmed by flies upstairs and hears a hostile voice ordering him to leave, causing him to flee. The next day, Kathy's aunt Helena, a nun, visits the house but becomes violently ill and leaves abruptly, confounding Kathy.

Attack of the priest preceded by flies on the window



However, I don't think a mirror was a significant part until Amityville:
A New Generation

Once inside, the mirror is haunted, having seen evil, so like the mirror in From Beyond the Grave, and in Dead of Night (1945), it embodies a demon, and since the mirror reflects oneself, it reflects one’s dead self, and projects evil into one (all of this based on traditional folk fears of mirrors as soul-stealing and spirit-trapping places). In this set up, the art is just art, but, then, backed up by the mirror, it becomes haunted painting, or painting which is a straightforward creativity-denying projection of artist angst, in this case their being possessed by the devil. So, in murder one, a spurned pickup comes up to Suki’s studio where the mirror is and begins a full on episode of revenge iconoclasm, destroying her paintings, because they represent her, he will probably slash her, if she shows up too. So, we see paintings punctured, it looks like modern art and Jack the Dripper too, but, no, it is not art (Fontana), it is anger, destroying art. And then when in his state of hauntedness, the demon having come into him, he looks into the mirror, with, by the way, rather implausibly gothic efforts in the frame, he sees himself possessed by the demon, and marked for death.


